# Передача данных между 2 открытыми фрагментами

Tags: java, android

Для обычной передачи от одного фрагмента в другое с его заменой можно использовать:

```
Fragment f = new EmployeeDetails();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("ID", "123");
f.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f);
ft.commit();
```

Но что делать, если на экране находится два разных активных фрагмента? Как происходит взаимодействие?

Comment: можно попробовать через интерфейс который будет связывать два фрагмента через родительскую активность

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko типо во фрагменте A объявить интерфейс, в Activity реализовать интерфейс и переопределить метод в нем, и уже там передавать во фрагмент B через Bundle?

Comment: как вариант можно попробовать, иначе как сделать я с трудом представляю

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko просто меня это на собеседовании спрашивали, а я даже  такие Layout не реализовывал, где применяются  2 фрагмента

Comment: это получается два контейнера сделать нужно будет которые расположены друг над другом или как-то иначе

Comment: все возможные  [взаимодействия между 2 фрагментами и активити](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html)